CompositeItemWriter having issue while persisting data
I wanted a single reader two processors and two writers. my processing logic is correct but data is not being persisted in DB, this is my composite writer
            @Bean
            public CompositeItemWriter<Object> compositeItemWriterr() {
                CompositeItemWriter<Object> writer = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
                writer.setDelegates( Arrays.asList(
                   (ItemWriter) classifierCompositeItemWriter(null),
                   (ItemWriter) schNamesWriter()
                   )
                );
               
                return writer;
            }

Both schNamesWriter and classifierCompositeItemWriter have different types So I am getting an error(cannot convert from ItemWriter to ItemWriter<? super Object>)here while adding it in delegate So I am using typecast. I guess this may be the issue because if I add only one specific type then data is being persisited in DB.

  public CompositeItemWriter<ScheProInfo> compositeItemWriterr() {
      CompositeItemWriter<ScheProInfo> writer = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
      writer.setDelegates( Arrays.asList(
        classifierCompositeItemWriter(null)
        )
      );
      
      return writer;
    }

Can please anyone suggest how can I use two different types of writers here?
I have tried a single type and data is being persisted but the issue is when adding two different types. Please let me know if more info is required.

"So I am getting an error here" where is the error log you are referring to?

sorry i forgot to mention that, this is the error- Type mismatch: cannot convert from ItemWriter to ItemWriter<? super Object>

[Edit] your question and add the error details from your comment to your question.
